# ds = data_set(sys.argv[1]) IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I found the code in GitHUB, I would like to load an image and run this script, so that it can detect corroded areas from an image.

This is for python programming language to analyze corroded areas in an image using Weak-classifier Colour-based Corrosion Detector.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    ds = data_set(sys.argv[1])

    for j in ds:
        item_detect(j)
```

Full python code:https://github.com/I159/corrosion_detector_poc

Comment: youre not passing in an argument when youre running this script

Comment: How exactly areyou running this program? `sys.argv` reads the argguments passed to the command line so you need to run it something like: `python main.py image/path`. Or if you are using an IDE you have to configure the run

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through the code in github,

While running the detector.py file,

**you need to give the location of your dataset file while running detector.py as an argument**.

```
python detector.py location_of_that_data_set_file
```

like

```
python detector.py /var/downloads/dataset.csv
```

Hope you have dataset,

While clinking this [DataSetLink](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wbn5xraxqn3x8dq/AADnFTO_8V_HMd4lsshtkF6La?dl=0) i see that link is not found, Hope you have that dataset downloaded in one location.

So, Pass the downloaded dataset location to the python detector.py

Answer (score 0):

The input parameter from cmd id missing. I have implemented a little example for you:

```
import sys
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("The zero index in argv list is always the name of script: {}".format(sys.argv[0]))
    print("First input argument from cmd: {}".format(sys.argv[1]))
```

As you see the 1 index in `argv` contains the first input parameter from cmd which is missing from your code.

Output:

```
>>>python3 test.py Input_parameter_from_cmd
The zero index in argv list is always the name of script: test.py
First input argument from cmd: Input_parameter_from_cmd
```

In your case the Python script waits the path of your data-set which has to be the first input parameter from cmd.